# int somme (int t, int tab[]){ if(t==0) return 0; return tab[t-1]+somme(t-1,tab); } please explain this code to me

Tags: c, recursion

```
int somme(int t, int tab[])
{
    if (t == 0)
         return 0;
    
    return tab[t - 1] + somme(t - 1, tab);
}
```

I do not understand how it works to come up with the sum of the elements of the array.

I expected to have sum from the last element but it seems nor to be working.

Comment: Might help to draw it on paper for an array of 2 elements.

Comment: What does your beginners books, tutorials or class say about *recursion*?

Comment: Do you understand what **recursion** is? It is a function that calls itself until a stop condition is reached. This is a recursive function. It iterates through the `tab` array starting at the last element until it reaches  the first element, adding them together.

Comment: "I expected to have sum from the last element but it seems nor to be working." --> Post a [mcve].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If it's a good one, it doesn't mention recursion at all. Nor goto, setjmp or other such dangerous tricks which should pretty much never be used.

Comment: You might want to rephrase the question title to not include the whole code. Asking for "How does the function that calls itself work" would guide answerers better.

Comment: Stuff your function full with loglines, showing the value of `t`, `tab` and `tab[t]`, and check what happens.

Comment: Please Dominique how can I add it properly.

Answer (score 1):

If an array has no elements, then its sum is 0.  Otherwise it is the value of the last element plus the sum of all previous elements.

Comment: @Junias To add on this: Of course, the array does not change but in each step the function is given another size. That means is looks like the "last element" is moving to the start of the array until all the function sees looks like an empty array which is where recursion stops.

Comment: Given that it returns the last first element why puting tab[t-1]

Comment: Array of size t goes from 0 to t-1